# how to make rest call with key and secret using md5 in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to implement rest call with key and secret using md5. I tried a way but its giving me an error,

{"status":"error","message":"Signature mismatch"}.

Please help me, its very urjent!!

## this is my md5 method,

```
private static final String md5(final String parem) {
    try {
        // Create MD5 Hash
        MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest
                .getInstance("MD5");
        digest.update(parem.getBytes());
        byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

        // Create Hex String
        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++) {
            String h = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
            while (h.length() < 2)
                h = "0" + h;
            hexString.append(h);
        }
        return hexString.toString();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add some input and output?

Answer (score 0):

I did try with one of my classes and found only one difference:

Yours: 
Input: test
Output: `098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6`

Mine: 
Input: test
Output: `098F6BCD4621D373CADE4E832627B4F6`

So only one diff, the uppercase....

if that does not solve it, i would say have a look if your hashing the correct data.

Comment: In your question you do mention Signature mismatch.... an MD5 is not a signature. encryptWithPrivateKey(MD5(message)) is a sinature, can it be that you missed a step?

Comment: what I am doing is, I am getting user details from facebook account and using those values i am creating param string for md5 method to get signature,

Comment: String param = "name" + first_name + last_name + "email"
        + email + "facebook_user_id" + facebook_user_id
        + "location" + location + "zip_code" + zip_code
        + "birthday" + birthday + "time" + time
        + "api_key" + api_key;

      String signature = md5(param);
      Post_Method_Interface commonPost = new CommonPostMethod();
      getResponceForParse = commonPost
        .FacebookLoginModel(first_name + last_name,
          email, facebook_user_id, location,
          zip_code, birthday, time, api_key,
          signature);

Comment: Don't reinvent the week, just use the facebook sdk, all you need is there.

Comment: but we have to use this way for other services too, please help us ,, i m using this for login service

Comment: Best you make a new question and give the exact explanation and code. Comments are getting very long. Somebody with Facebook experience can then help you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19052/discussion-between-user1798222-and-frank)